# addEventListener has no effect when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="MouseEvent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" ></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var handleclick = function(event)
{
document.body.style.bgColor="red";
};

var button = document.getElementById("btn");
button.addEventListener('click',handleclick,false);
```

For some reason when "btn" is clicked the background color does not change,what is going wrong here? thx

Comment: wrap your last two lines in `window.onload`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your JavaScript console. You will see that it is complaining that `addEventListener` is not a function because `button` is undefined.

Your script runs before the the button has been parsed into the DOM.

Move the script so it is after the button.

Alternatively, wrap the last two lines in a function and `addEventListener('load', thatFunction)`.

---

Additionally, there is no `bgColor` property of `style`, you want `backgroundColor`.

Comment: @eghawk2k if this solution helps you do accept this answer.